# Blackberry firewall "connection inside and outside the firewall" problem

Tags: blackberry, networking, firewall

Device is  8900 OS version 4.6.1

Getting this exception/message

*The application atempted to open a connection to a location inside the firewall and outside the firewall which is not allowed by your security policy*

when trying to open an http connection when firewall is on (allowed HTTP connections for the app when prompted). Exact same code works fine on other devices with firewall on.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The firewall in this case is actually the BES firewall - what you're encountering is known as the "split-pipe" scenario where the device is detecting that connections are being made both inside the firewall (via MDS) and outside the firewall (via Wi-Fi, Direct TCP, etc.)  There are IT policies that can be enabled by the BES administrator to prevent "split-pipes" from happening.  Here's a good forum post with more information:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206252#M29108